# Is there a service that offers hosted virtual machines for testing desktop software against different OSes?

Tags: windows, hosting, virtual-machine

I've got a desktop app that I (as a developer) need to do testing against and a remote QA team also needs to test against.  The app is a plugin for some B2B software, so there's 2 major variables that I need to consider:

1. OS Version
2. [B2B Software] Version

That makes for a lot of potential images.

Because VM images are so large, it would be painful to have to do share images by sending files back and forth.  It would be great if there was some hosted service that would allow me and QA to quickly and easily create, clone, and restore images from a known last state.

I'm basically looking for a Rackspace or Windows Azure-type service, *but for client OSes*.  Does this exist?

Comment: There's [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) for browser testing... but I'm unaware of a similar service that lets you pre-define your own VM images. We use VSphere servers where I work, but that's definitely not cloud based, requires a load of servers and storage space etc. etc.

Comment: If they have this stuff for testing email (I forget the name of the service), and they have it for browsers, there has to be one for client OSes.  It's too painful testing desktop software for there not to be one.  I smell a bounty...